# Spring Boot - Couchbase auto-index is not working

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I have implemented a project with spring boot and couchbase.

I also defined auto-index:true . On Couchbase console , I can see the views under "Production Views" section but coucshbase still gives me the error below:

```
No index available on keyspace todolist that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online
```

So can someone tell me that what I am missing?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this in your CouchbaseConfig class.

```
@Override
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_INDEX_MANAGER)
@Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_INDEX_MANAGER)
public IndexManager indexManager() {
        return new IndexManager(true, true, true);
}
```

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was running tests against a new bucket in couchbase.

The @N1qlPrimaryIndexed and @ViewIndexed annotations only seemed to create the indexes when I ran the Spring Boot app as an executable Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase does not recommend using both @N1qlPrimaryIndexed and @ViewIndexed, they are only useful during development

@ViewIndexed - views are on their way out of couchbase, and there are just a few methods like deleteAll that still use them.

You can read a full explanation here:
https://docs.couchbase.com/tutorials/spring-data-indexes/spring-index.html